# How to prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty }\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}( -1)^n}{n!(2n+1)2^n}$ = $\frac{\sqrt {2π}}{2} $

Tags: integration, taylor-expansion

We are learning at the moment the Gauss curve in math class and my teacher told me that the area under the graph is 1. When I asked for its proof, she said that it requires some crazy application of integral-techniques which wouldn't be obvious to come up with, which I accepted at that time, but it bothered me at home and I gave it a try to prove it but by using the Taylor series. I'll spare you the calculation, but I have proven(using the ratio test) that it's possible that the following power series for any real value x(including $+\infty$) will converge: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{x^{2n+1}( -1)^n}{n!(2n+1)2^n}$ I have put this into my calculator and found that it would be equal to $\frac{\sqrt {2π}}{2} $ , which if proven, would immediately imply that the area is indeed 1. But this is easier said then done, so could you help me with proving that this power series will equal to $\frac{\sqrt {2π} }{2}$ for x going to $+\infty$? I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: The way it's normally shown is by taking the integral squared,  using powerful math to say that you can convert that into a double integral,  then convert it into polar coordinates which makes the integration trivial, fyi

Comment: You've been here long enough to realize that it's customary to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: It should be readable by now.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that the radius of convergence of this series is $\infty$. We therefore have the function
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}( -1)^n}{n!(2n+1)2^n}\qquad(-\infty<x<\infty)\ .$$
It follows that
$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{(-x^2/2)^n\over n!}=e^{-x^2/2}\ .$$
As $f(0)=0$ we therefore obtain
$$f(x)=\int_0^x f'(t)\>dt=\int_0^xe^{-t^2/2}\>dt\to{\sqrt{2\pi}\over2}\qquad(x\to\infty)\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $J=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}dx.$ Then $$J^2=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}dx \cdot\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-y^2}dy=$$ $$=\int\int_{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2}e^{-x^2-y^2}dxdy.$$ Converting to polar co-ordinates,i.e. $x=r\cos t,\,y=r\sin t$ with $r\in [0,\infty)$ and $t\in [0,2\pi),$ we must replace $dxdy$ with $rdrdt,$ and we also have $x^2+y^2=r^2 ,$ so $$J^2=\int_{t=0}^{2\pi}\left(\int_{r=0}^{+\infty}re^{-r^2}dr\,\right)dt=\int_{t=0}^{2\pi}(1 /2)dt=\pi.$$

[ If  $u=r^2$ then $\int re^{-r^2}dr=\int e^{-r^2}d(r^2)/2=\int e^{-u}du/2=-e^{-u}/2=-e^{-r^2}/2. ]$

More cautiously, for $A>0$ let $$S(A)=\int_{|x|\le A}\int_{|y|\le A}e^{-x^2-y^2}dxdy$$ and let $$C(A)=\int\int_{x^2+y^2\le A^2}e^{-x^2-y^2}dxdy=\int_{t=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^Are^{-r^2}drdt=2\pi\frac {1-e^{-A^2}}{2}.$$  We have $C(A)<S(A)<C(A\sqrt 2),$ while $S(A)\to J^2$ and $C(A)\to\pi$ as $A\to\infty.$